# How do I remove the extra 1 cent in woocommerce checkout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am having an issue whereby woocommerce add 1 cent extra on top of my stacked discount.

So my price is $100. I give 2 unique coupon with discount value of 10% each. Tax is 10%
What happen is I expect user to pay $88. But eventually, there is an additional 0.01 cent.

I tried looking for solution here, but there don't seem to have any conclusion. The issue keeps resurfacing. So is there any way I can manipulate the price? Like after calculate total, how do I change the price before it reaches payment gateway?

Here is the link to the reported issues:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/20997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know where the problem comes from. But you can use this solution.

You can round the product price using `Woocommerce` filter.

Copy this code in functions.php in your child theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'round_woocommrce_price', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_variation_regular_price', 'round_woocommrce_price', 99);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_variation_price', 'round_woocommrce_price', 99);
add_filter('raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_woocommrce_price' );
function round_woocommrce_price($price, $product = NULL) {
    // you can return this, if you are interested: floor($price) + 0.99
    return floor($price);
}
```